# Switch from sum to integral in non-Cartesian coordinates

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

when I do the BZ integral in honeycomb lattice numerically I need to calculate:
$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{{\partial {k_x}}}{{\partial {{k'}_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {k_y}}}{{\partial {{k'}_1}}}}\\
{\frac{{\partial {k_x}}}{{\partial {{k'}_2}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {k_y}}}{{\partial {{k'}_2}}}}
\end{array}} \right|\iint_{BZ}f(k_x,k_y) d{k_x}d{k_y} =
\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {f({{k'}_1}{{\bf{b}}_1} + {{k'}_2}{{\bf{b}}_2})d{{k'}_1}d} } {k'_2}$$

with

$${{k'}_1} = {k_x},{{k'}_2} = \frac{{{k_x}}}{2} + \frac{{\sqrt 3 {k_y}}}{2}$$

my question is ,when I calculate the RHS of the first Eq numerically, can I transform it to discrete sum dispite of $b_1,b_2$ is not orthogonal?
$$
\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {f({{k'}_1}{{\bf{b}}_1} + {{k'}_2}{{\bf{b}}_2})d{{k'}_1}d} } {k'_2} = \frac{{4{\pi ^2}}}{{{L_x}{L_y}}}\sum_{m = 0}^{{L_x}} {\sum_{n = 0}^{{L_y}} {f\left(\frac{{2\pi m}}{{{L_x}}}{{\bf{b}}_1} + \frac{{2\pi n}}{{{L_x}}}{{\bf{b}}_2}\right)} }$$

if I can do that, the weird thing is that, we can associate integral to discrete sum despite of the choose of coordinate ($k_1,k_2$ looks like in the basis $b_1,b_2$ and $k_x,k_y$ seems like in the basis $x,y$) directly. However, we need to add the jacobian when we do the integral in different coordinate.

Comment: Have you tried Math stack exchange?

Comment: thanks, I post my question here because I think it's a basic technique of physics